# Mac OS change value of bound core data control

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode8, cocoa-bindings, macos-sierra

I'm just getting started with Core Data.  I have an XCode 8 Swift 3 project with a form with an Array Controller and several bound controls.  The form works perfectly saving and recalling data from Core Data.

I want to put a button on the form that will set values in a couple of the bound text boxes.  I can set the stringValue property of the text boxes and it does change the displayed data, but it does not save the data.  When I move to another record and come back I see the old value.

How do I set the new value so it will be updated in the Core Data store?

Comment: Update the data in the array controller

Comment: Please provide more information on how the text boxes are bound. To a selection of the arrayController?

Comment: Please see the discussion below and see if that answers your question.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the data in the array controller.

Test app:

- Create a new Xcode project, macOS Cocoa application, Swift, use Core Data.
- Go to MainMenu.xib and add a `NSArrayController`.
- Show AppDelegate.swift in the assistant editor and MainMenu.xib in the standard editor (or the other way around).
- Control drag or right drag from the `NSArrayController` to the line below `@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!` to create an outlet.

Example of setting the data in the array controller:

```
for person in arrayController.selectedObjects as! [Person] {
    person.name = "John"
    person.address = "Street 1"
}
```

`Person` is the `NSManagedObject` subclass. `name` and `address` are the properties shown in the text boxes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15391033)

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg I don't know what to add to the answer. Do you know how `NSArrayController` and Core Data work?

Comment: How do I reference the array controller from the code?

Comment: How do you reference the text boxes? Which data from the array controller is displayed in the text boxes?

Comment: I can reference the text boxes by right dragging into the swift file and creating an outlet.  It won't let me do that with the Array Controller, which I created by dragging onto the Interface Builder and binding it to an entity in my Core Data model.  The text boxes are bound to fields through the Connections Inspector, not in code.

Comment: Creating an outlet for the array controller should work. Can you tell a bit more about how the text boxes and the array controller are connected? Which object handles the action of the button?

Comment: In the Bindings Inspector (not the Connections Inspector) for the text box, under Value, Bind to "Array Controller," Controller Key "selection," Model Key Path <field name>.  The button action is in AppDelegate.Swift.  This is a very simple application.  I'm new to Swift, XCode, and Core Data so I very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Storyboard? Put the action of the button and the outlet for the array controller in the view controller.

Comment: OK so I may need more study on this.  From what I've learned so far I thought view controllers and storyboards were mainly for iOS apps rather than MacOS.  (And I thought I had specified this was a MacOS app in my original question but I see I did not. My apologies.)

Comment: I'm doing a lot of guessing. Storyboard? Document based app? Subclass of `NSWindowController`? Which object (class) is the owner of the XIB of the array controller?

Comment: OK I'll do as well as I can describing what I have.  I started a new project that included Core Data.  It is not document based.  I created one entity in the data model with several fields.  I dragged an Array Controller to the Interface builder, which shows up in the left pane when viewing the MainMenu.xib file.  It is bound to the App Delegate's managed object context using the Bindings Inspector.  I added a list box and a few text boxes to the form, also binding them with the bindings inspector.  So I was viewing, editing, and saving data without writing any code.  (continued next comment)

Comment: I then added a button and right-clicked and dragged to add an action to the AppDelegate.swift file.  That's where I'm trying to write code to update a text box and the array controller data.  (where I said list box above, I meant table view)

Comment: Is it possible to create an outlet for the array controller in AppDelegate, like the window outlet?

Comment: That's pretty much my question.

Comment: My answer is yes, control drag.

Comment: That was the very first thing I tried and it didn't work.  If you'll confirm it works for you I'd like to explore how your configuration is different than mine (if you're willing).

Comment: Yes, thank you, control drag did add an outlet.  So now I'm struggling with updating the field.  I would expect to do it with one of the the .setValue functions of the array controller but I can't get it to work.  Any hints?  I do appreciate you staying with me on this.  It started out seeming like this was all going to be fairly simple but now... not so much.

Comment: Willike, your edited answer above works perfectly.  Thank you!